# Array not updating in for loop

Tags: python

```
L_list = np.array([7,8,9])
one_list = [1] * 3
L_vec = np.diag(one_list) # making a 2d array with 1s in diagonal position

for j in range(2):
    for i in range(1, 3):
        L_vec[i,j] = L_list[j]
```

I want to set up 3x3 L_vec with 1s in diagonal position and update the the L_vec with elements in L_list.

I went through the debug and nothing is changing. I can't figure out why. Can you explain what is going on?

Comment: when I use `print(L_vec)` befor loop and after loop then I see different values - so it updates `L_vec`. `[[1 0 0]  [7 8 0]  [7 8 1]]`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `print(L_vec)` after your code shows me this:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [7 8 0]
 [7 8 1]]
```

So, something has definitely changed. Is this not the result you expected to get, or did you mean something else by "nothing is changing"?

Comment: When I was running it didnt change at all from [[1,0,0], [0,1,0],[0,0,1]]

Comment: So if you add ```print(L_vec)``` after your code it does not print out the array that I've put in my answer?